# upload image using an html form in symfony 3

Tags: php, html, symfony

i am using symfony 3.4 , i am trying to upload images using an HTML form .when i select an image and i submit the form i get this error  : 
"Call to a member function move() on string"

this is my  html.twig file ( the form part)  :

```
 <form role="form" id="contact_form" class="contact-form" method="post" action="{{ path('publier_offre') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" class="form-control" name="" id="imageOffre">                                         
                        </form>
```

and this the controller action ( where to get the uploaded image and persisting it to the database ) :

```
 public function publierOffreAction(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('POST')){
            $offre = new offre();
            //getting the image file
            $filename = $request->files->get('imageOffre');
            $filename->move(
                $this->getParameter('image_directory'),$filename
            );
            $offre->setImage($filename);
            //getting the image file
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->merge($offre);
            $em->flush();
        }
        return $this->render('@offer/Default/publieroffre.html.twig');
    }
```

here is the image attribute in my entity file offer.php :

```
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="plz enter an image")
     * @Assert\Image()
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $image ;  

 /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $image
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }
```

and this the default upload directory ( config.yml ) :

```
parameters:
    locale: en
    image_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/web/uploads/images'
```

i am suggesting that i am not getting the uploaded image in a correct way in the controller . please help and thanks

Comment: Well, your `input name` is blank in this code... and you should use `->files` instead of `->get`

Comment: @msg thank you for your answer , i will try to add the name and back to you with the feedbacks

Comment: And you probably need to set the enctype to multipart/form-data: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Comment: @sbrn Yeah, good catch, using `form` twig functions usually takes care of that automatically...

Comment: update : i got this error "Call to a member function move() on string" after adding the input name

Comment: @sbrn still getting the same error even after adding "enctype="multipart/form-data" to my form

Comment: Please read the comment of @msg carefully: use ‘->files’ instead of ‘->get’ on the $request

Comment: @sbrn yes i have already added ->files->get and it still showing the same error : 
" Call to a member function move() on null "

Comment: can you add you formType plz?

Comment: Hi, could you paste error log here? Thanks